# Simple moon figure with pst-intersect gives an unevenness

Tags: pstricks

Simple moon figure with pst-intersect gives an unevenness. How can this be prevented?

[image: moon]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-intersect}

\begin{document}

\psset
{
    unit=0.001,
    linewidth=0.1pt,
}

\begin{pspicture}(18000,5000)

\pssavepath[linestyle=none]{c1}{\pscircle(2615,1850){500}}
\pssavepath[linestyle=none]{c2}{\pscircle(3085,2100){500}}

% get intersections
\psintersect[name=i]{c1}{c2}

% draw and fill
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=yellow]{
    \pstracecurve[istart=1, istop=2]{i}{c1}
    \pstracecurve[istart=2, istop=1]{i}{c2}
}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `linejoin`

\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=yellow, linejoin=2]{

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why, but I solved it by swapping lines 22 and 23.